# How to change default properties of built-in browser?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Some applications use [WebBrowser object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752085(VS.85).aspx) built-in to display Html. Seems like all them embed default .NET object, so there aren't really any settings, but I want to disable javascript in such windows. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation for this control [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) it seems to indicate that this is just a wrapper for the ActiveX web browser control, which based on the [About the Broswer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) section indicates that its just IE. Have you tried disabling scripts via the 'Internet Options' Control Panel applet?